# Scan number in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly

A few days ago I started learning assembly and I have a question. I have a simple program which gets a number and shows it on the screen. But it doesn't seem to work. When I type in terminal `gcc -m32 p2.s` I get:

```
p2.s: Assembler messages:
p2.s:2: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:3: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:4: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:5: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:9: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:10: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:11: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:13: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:15: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:16: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:17: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:19: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:20: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
p2.s:21: Error: invalid character (0xc2) in mnemonic
```

my code:

```
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .global main
    .text
   
main:

# scanf("%d", scan);
    push offset liczba
    push offset scan
    call scanf
    add esp, 8
   
# printf("Hello, world: %d\n", scan);
    push liczba
    push offset komunikat
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    ret
   
    .data
komunikat: .asciz "Hello, world: %d\n"
scan: .asciz "%d"
liczba: .int
```

Could you please kindly help me?

Comment: You managed to put unicode characters into your program. Clean them up. The code you posted seems fine, maybe just copy-paste it back :) PS: the final `liczba: .int` needs an initializer.

Comment: Looks like you're using some rich text editor.  Switch to a simple text editor or use an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this command in the prompt shell to remove the invalid character from the file.

```
sed -i 's/find/replace/g' file
```

Try this in your scenario

```
sed -i 's/\xc2//g' p2.s
```